# JPA @OneToMany association saves id with null value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I'm actually trying to define a relationship between two entities managed by JPA (called Aggregate1 and Aggregate2 in my example) with a mapping table represented as another JPA entity (called Association)

Here is the definition of the Aggregate1 class :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "aggregate1")
public class Aggregate1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long                   id;
    @Column
    private String                 something;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "aggregate1_id")
    private final Set<Association> associations = new HashSet<>();

    public Aggregate1(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

    // methods to add, update and remove association omitted
}
```

And the definition of the Association class :

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "association")
public class Association implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "aggregate1_id")
    private final Long        aggregate1Id;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "aggregate2_id")
    private final Long        aggregate2Id;
    @Column(name = "association_value")
    private final String      associationValue;

    // methods omitted
}
```

You can find a complete example of running code [here](https://github.com/Alexandre-Carbenay/demo-jpa-onetomany).

I know the standard way of representing a many to many relation between two entities is to use the `@ManyToMany` association (as described in this [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)), but I don't want to link directly `Aggregate1` and `Aggregate2` entities, but rather link them through identities. And I don't need the link from `Aggregate2` to `Aggregate1`.

So using this JPA mapping, I can indeed retrieve an `Aggregate1` with its `Association`s, but when I try to add a new association, setting explicitly the associated aggregates identities in the new `Association` entity, an exception is thrown as the following :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "AGGREGATE1_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into association (association_value, aggregate2_id, aggregate1_id) values (?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
```

Here is the Hibernate log occurring during the save :

```
2018-02-23 10:13:36.664 DEBUG 9076 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select associatio0_.aggregate2_id as aggregat1_2_0_, associatio0_.aggregate1_id as aggregat2_2_0_, associatio0_.association_value as associat3_2_0_ from association associatio0_ where associatio0_.aggregate2_id=? and associatio0_.aggregate1_id=?
2018-02-23 10:13:36.666 TRACE 9076 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [3]
2018-02-23 10:13:36.666 TRACE 9076 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-02-23 10:13:36.686 DEBUG 9076 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into association (association_value, aggregate2_id, aggregate1_id) values (?, ?, ?)
2018-02-23 10:13:36.687 TRACE 9076 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [test association]
2018-02-23 10:13:36.687 TRACE 9076 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2018-02-23 10:13:36.687 TRACE 9076 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2018-02-23 10:13:36.688  WARN 9076 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
2018-02-23 10:13:36.688 ERROR 9076 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "AGGREGATE1_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into association (association_value, aggregate2_id, aggregate1_id) values (?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
```

So the values are correctly set, as the initial select in association table shows, but then it seems that the `aggregate1Id` and `aggregate2Id` attributes values are reset to null before saving.

Can anyone explain what happen exactly during the save, and why those values are reset to null ?

Comment: You have a class with 2 `@Id` fields, so where is your `@IdClass` ?

Comment: and if that is the problem, you need to report a bug on your chosen JPA provider for not telling you to provide one!

Comment: OK with this @IdClass definition, the problem is solved. Thanks DN1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution proposed by DN1 works, the following `AssociationId` class was actually missing :

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AssociationId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Long        aggregate1Id;
    private final Long        aggregate2Id;

}
```

And, in the `Association` class, the @IdClass annotation must be defined as :

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "association")
@IdClass(AssociationId.class)
public class Association implements Serializable {
...
}
```

**--- Edit ---**

To be able to add and delete associations, the `Aggregate1` entity definition must be updated with those changes :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "aggregate1")
public class Aggregate1 {

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "aggregate1Id", cascade = { ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    private final Set<Association> associations = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```